# How to install/use confluent hub cli with Confluent Kafka Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to install an MQTT connector to Kafka Connect running in Docker. I've seen how to do it manually but curious if its possible to use the confluent hub cli with the docker deployment of Confluent Enterprise Kafka.

https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-mqtt/

I did also look at this guide for installing the JDBC connector manually via Docker. 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/installation/connect-avro-jdbc.html

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `-e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars -v /tmp/quickstart/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars` will work "better" and you wouldn't be running `confluent-hub install` everytime the container starts up